# My INSERT INTO from staging into my ods is throwing an error when it comes to my date column, what can I change about my code?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've loaded my data into staging, which went smoothly across the board, but now when trying to insert my data from staging into the ods my sql errors out. All tables moved without error with the exception of `temperature_tmp` and `precipitation_tmp`, which have the `TO_DATE` function.

I end up getting this error:

> Can't parse 'date' as date with format 'YYYYMMDD'

I'm at a loss as to why this is happening, I tried `TRY_TO_DATE` and that threw a different error because the first row of the `precipitation_tmp` table has the headers from loading the data.

Query:

```
INSERT INTO precipitation(date_t, precipitation, precipitation_normal)
    SELECT 
        TO_DATE(date_tmp,'YYYYMMDD'), 
        CAST(precipitation_tmp AS FLOAT), 
        CAST(precipitation_normal AS FLOAT) 
    FROM 
        "UDACITYPROJECT"."STAGING".precipitation_tmp;
```

This is for a school project.

Comment: Please show your staging table DDL definitions.  What data type are you storing your date value in?

Comment: If you have header records in your staging data table, you need to modify your query to exclude them from the processing.  Furthermore this likely means all your data is loaded as a string type ... and that your to_date() call is likely failing because the header record in your data set doesn't match the YYYYMMDD format.

Comment: That makes sense @JimDemitriou I'm looking into how to exclude that first row, or skip it rather. If/when I'm able to do that, the to_date() should work as intended yeah?

Comment: It should, assuming all your date strings meet that format and are valid dates.  TRY_TO_DATE is a way to scan your data to determine how many records fail the quality test:  select date_tmp from UDACITYPROJECT"."STAGING".precipitation_tmp where try_to_date (date_tmp,'YYYYMMDD') is NULL should give you a list of every value that fails that test.

Comment: Found my problem, reviewed my code. I missed  the skip_header=1 at the end of my copy into line... Thank you for the insight Jim, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Found my problem, and reviewed my code. I missed the `skip_header=1` at the end of my copy into line... Thank you for the insight Jim, appreciate the help